# Client-side Javascript Authentication Scheme

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, cross-domain

Assume you have 2 servers on 2 separate sub-domains called client.example.com and server.example.com, is it possible to authenticate a user using only client side-javascript on client.example.com (no server-side component) and only server-side code (restful json api only)?

A good practical example of this would be to create a client-side only twitter component that does things like post tweets which require authentication. (Right now twitter will open another window which uses their domain for the browser to send the appropriate cookies with the session_id, but assuming we can change that).